# Recode by comparing a value to numbers in a vector

Tags: r

I want to code the values in a column into fewer values in another column. 
For example, 
if the value in zipcode  column is one of the following c(90272,90049,90077,90210,90046,90069,90024,90025,90048,90036,90038,90028),
code it as "west" in district column.
How can I do it in R?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `ifelse()` function.

Set up the data in a dataframe:

```
df <- data.frame(zipcode = c(90272,90049,90077,90210,90046,90069,90024,90025,90048,90036,90038,90028))
```

Then use `ifelse()` to code a new value based on the values of `zipcode`.

```
df$district <- ifelse(df$zipcode %in% c(90272,90049,90077,90210,90046,90069,90024,90025,90048,90036,90038,90028),
   "west",
   NA)

> df
   zipcode region
1    90272   west
2    90049   west
3    90077   west
4    90210   west
5    90046   west
6    90069   west
7    90024   west
8    90025   west
9    90048   west
10   90036   west
11   90038   west
12   90028   west
```